# DOM button onblur event not fired on mac osx safari and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

I try to add "onblur" to a button node:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzfg0pdh/2/

```
<input type="button" onblur="console.log('blur');" value="button" />
```

but the handler doesn't work on Mac osx Safari & Firefox.

Browsers can work:
Chrome 39.0.2171.99 Mac OS X 10_9_4 AppleWebKit/537.36
Firefox 35 Windows 7

Browsers can't work:
Safari 7.0.5 Mac OS X 10_9_4 AppleWebKit/537.77.4
Firefox 35 Mac OS X 10_9_4

Comment: Could you trying registering the handlers using `addEventListener` instead?  Also, please post any errors or warnings you get in your console.

Comment: There are known issues with focus and blur events on buttons and links on macs, not sure if this is one of those, but I think quirksmode have an overview

Comment: I can confirm that this jsFiddle **works** on Safari 8.0.1 and Firefox 31 on OSX Yosemite (10.10.1).

Comment: @rioc0719  I tried http://jsfiddle.net/kzfg0pdh/4/, still not work on Safari on Mac OS X . There is no errors or warnings in console

Comment: @smilingwang I don't have a Mac, so I can't test anything, but according to [this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) Safari has problems with onblur and onfocus. Also, your fiddle can be confirmed working in Chrome 41 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: @rioc0719  I tried browserstack and get the same problem.  I add click handler to fire the foucs event and then I get blur.  a temporary fix. http://jsfiddle.net/kzfg0pdh/6/

Comment: I think click and clickOutSide event my be better for my problem.